# What are the long-term benefits/consequences of leaving an average, comfortable job in France for a high-paying job in UAE?

Tags: france, job-hopping, uae

My profile: I am French, single, I graduated from an engineering school in 2016, worked as Computer Vision engineer for two years, and did a PhD in AI (in a very large R&D company) which I completed two months ago. Then I got a data scientist job at a very large French company (>100k employees worldwide). I have about 5yrs work experience right now.

Overall, things are going well, the working environment is quite good, but the salary is lower than I wanted: *before taxes*, 48k€ + at most 10k€ counting all possible bonuses (*13e mois*, performance bonus, savings account, etc.). However, a little before starting this job, a recruiter for a tech company (~500 people) in Abu Dhabi contacted me and I replied and went through interviews out of curiosity. The result: they are about to offer a job with a ~100k€ salary + 10% bonus + health care, all tax-free.

In terms of comfort, I prefer to stay where I am in the Paris region. However, it really hurts when I count how much money I have left. In France, I get about 36k€ after taxes. So, counting about 2k€ / mo for basic expenses (rent, food, electricity, car, etc.), I have about 15k€ left / year. And if I have any large expense like a new car, I go negative. In the UAE, after basic expenses (2k€/mo) and depending on how much I contribute to the French retirement accounts, I'll get ~60k€ to ~80k€ with no taxes!

To sum up, pros/cons of staying in France:

- **Pros**: Safe (and hard to get) job, close to family, good working environment
- **Cons**: Low pay, promotion to management jobs unlikely in the short-term (at least 2-3yrs)

Pro/cons of going to the UAE:

- **Pros**: Much higher pay, (possibly) more promotion opportunities
- **Cons**: Low job safety, far from family, unknown long-term perspectives, unknown work environment, hot climate, Islamic law, less privacy.

I do not want to miss a huge opportunity but I am afraid of ruining future career prospects in France, as I intend to return in 2-3yrs. And that's without counting that I'll have to leave a nice company and a nice boss 2 months in the probation period. Kinda feeling like I am betraying someone.

**What should I do? Any advice?**

PS: if you have any comment on manual contribution to French retirement accounts, I'd be happy to read them although it's a separate topic.

Comment: One of the easiest questions I have seen on this site! How could you not take the offer?

Comment: I did take it, but it was a hard decision. My family is in France and my previous employer is great on many points: WFH, vacations...  but not pay, which is barely average (well, for the average dude, not the CEO). What made me decide for the UAE in the end is the math and the higher ranking of the new job: I'll be years ahead there in terms of wealth and career. 

And why the downvotes? The choice does not seem obvious to me. I wanted to know if I missed some crucial detail or long-term impact I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, in current unstable situation, higher paying job is much more attractive then a lower paying one.

Consider this, in both positions it doesn`t work out after a year and you leave.

If France you have ~15k safety funds to find a new position, in UAE  ~80k

Question, how urgent do you need a new job in any of the cases?

Math gets even better as time goes.

P.S.

I guess your gender can also be a consideration, based on UAE as work location

Comment: I am a man and right now I would not need a job urgently (I have a 6 month safety fund).

Comment: @user133192 Perfect settings to build it up a bit  :)